# How to make QR readers recognize my generated QR code?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, qr-code

I'm researching an idea I have for an app and it needs the ability to scan QR codes. I'm totally new to QR codes and have been looking online for a while and can't find the answer.

Say on my app I have users, these users can add pictures to their account and append a QR code to this single picture.

---

My question is, how do I generate a random QR code for a users image and how do I give other users the ability to scan this generated QR code so it navigates them to the corresponding image ?

---

I presume you have to save the QR code to some kind of server which the app can connect to so the users can recognize the code when scanning.

Side note: Ill be using javascript/html/css as the code for this app :)) Phonegap will compile it all for mobile use

Answer (score 1):

- For QR Code Generation/Read you can use QRCode Generation libraries. ( ex : [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing))
- You can find some properties of the user uploaded image and use that properties to generate the QR code. (ex: Some Histogram based values)
- There should be a mapping with the code(property) which used to generate the QRCode and user information. (ex: SQLLite Datebase)